# How to configure CloudWatch Logs Agent to ignore the /root/.aws/credentials file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

After the `awslogs-agent-setup.py` completes the CloudWatchLogs Agent runs as root user. It finds it credentials under `/root/.aws/credentials`.

On the machines other services are already using the `/root/.aws/credentials` and those credentials should not be shared.

There is a `/var/awslogs/etc/aws.conf` file and a first idea was to add the `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key` to this file and then run `sudo service awslogs restart`.

Unfortunately this did not do the trick. It still finds the `/root/.aws/credentials` first.

Comment: Great would be a command-line option `--profile=awslogs` for the `awslogs-agent-setup.py` script.

Answer (score -1):

This won't solve the problem of applications accessing all the credentials in the file, you CAN set application-specific credentials in that file, so that the application can have it's own identity and credentials. It looks like the log agent can use credentials from an `[AmazonCloudWatchAgent]` section.

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/create-cloudwatch-agent-configuration-file-wizard.html